# using GraphQL Mutations with Apollo Client and Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, redux-toolkit

I don't know If I'm doing this the right way, it's the first time I've implemented GraphQL Apollo Client with Redux Toolkit.

So I have a Thunk:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import {LOGIN_USER} from "../../graphql/mutations/auth";

export const Authenticate = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/login",
    async (data, thunkAPI) => {
        const {email, password} = data;
        const [login, { loading, error, data: user }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER,{
            variables: {
                email,
                password
            }
        });
        await login();
        if (error) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
        }
        console.log(user);
        return user;
    }

)
```

the mutation looks like this:

```
import {gql} from "graphql-tag";

export const LOGIN_USER = gql`
    mutation login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
        login(email: $email, password: $password) {
            id
            email
            name
            token
        }
    }
`;
```

However,  In my component, when I dispatch the action, nothing happens, I've checked the network tab, but there are no requests to my apollo server.

```
import {Authenticate} from "../../features/user/userActions";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(Authenticate({email, password}));
    };

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
```

I'd appreciate any provided help and support

Comment: I suspect it won't work since `useMutation` is a React hook and hooks can only be called from React functions and custom React hooks. They cannot be called from nested functions, loops, conditionally, etc... I'm not very familiar with GQL but if they had a non-React-hook mutation handler you could likely use that.

Comment: What you are asking to do is probably already handled by [redux-toolkit-query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) which seems is basically what the `useMutation` hook is doing, but with RTKQ it would be a `useMutation` hook returned from an API slice you create that would already be redux-connected. It would basically replace your GQL code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it won't work since useMutation is a React hook and hooks can only be called from React
The most important part is the Redux thunk.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { gql  } from "@apollo/client";
import { initializeApollo} from "@/lib/apolloClient";

 const CREATE_CART = gql`
   mutation createCart($cartInput: CartInput) {
   cartCreate(input: $cartInput) {
    cart {id}
     }}`;

export const createCart  = createAsyncThunk("send/cart", async(item)=> {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
    const request = await apolloClient.mutate({
        mutation: PRE_RENDER_LIST,
        variables:{}
    })
    const data = await request;
    console.log(data,"test result")
    //do  other stuff
 }
```

Now you should dispatch this CreateCart.

```
   const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(createCart(item);
   };
```

Now to update Redux store state
you should do it in  extraReducers(builder) method.

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
 name: 'cart',
 initialState,
 reducers: {
// omit existing reducers here
 },
  extraReducers(builder) {
builder
  .addCase(createCart.pending, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'loading'
  })
  .addCase(createCart.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'succeeded'
    // Add any fetched posts to the array
    state.posts = state.posts.concat(action.payload)
  })
  .addCase(createCart.rejected, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'failed'
    state.error = action.error.message
    })
    }
 })
```